# PHP json_encode 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to create a json with two (or more) arrays that can have other arrays inside. I did several tests, but I can never get a correct output. This is the output I would like to get to:

```
{
    "servizi" : [
        {"id": 1, "nomeservizio": "Menu","value": 1},
        {"id": 2, "nomeservizio": "Prenotazione","value": 0}
    ],

    "pietanze" : [

        {"tipopietanza": "PANINI","PANINI" : [
            {"id": 1, "nomepietanza": "Royal avec du fromage", "prezzo":      5.50, "ingredienti": "Hamburger di manzo, cetriolini sott'aceto, cheddar, cipolle, senape, ketchup"},
            {"id": 2, "nomepietanza": "Big Belly Burger", "prezzo": 5.50, "ingredienti": "Hamburger di manzo, cipolla,senape, salsa worchester, prezzemolo, aglio, peperone, lattuga"}
        ]},

        {"tipopietanza": "CONTORNI E STUZZICHINI", "CONTORNI E STUZZICHINI" :[
            {"id":1, "nomepietanza": "Caprese", "prezzo": 4.00, "ingredienti": "Mozzarella"},
            {"id":2, "nomepietanza": "Insalata", "prezzo": 3.50, "ingredienti": "Insalata"}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

I want to take the data from a database and this is the first part of the output where I get "servizi", now I want to get "pietanze" and put it like in the json I showed

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'taurosdb';

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "taurosdb");  

  $sql = "-query that takes me the "servizi"-";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
           $json_array = array();  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
           {  
                $json_array[] = $row;  
           }  
echo json_encode(array('servizi' => $json_array));

?>
```

Comment: Have you started out with PHP arrays then tried to encode them? Not sure where PHP fits in this now. Aware of tools like: https://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: @ficuscr first of all i wrote the json and checked it was valid, now i'm trying to create the same json by taking the data from a db, but I can't get the same result

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your array a variable so you can work with it. Instead of this:

```
echo json_encode(array('servizi' => $json_array));
```

You can say:

```
$my_big_array = ["servizi" => $json_array];
```

Then later on:

```
$my_big_array["pietanze"] = $some_other_data;
```

Then at the end you can output the JSON. Don't forget to set the Content-Type header.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($my_big_array);
```